# Can I use an unplugged freezer as storage if I leave it open overnight?

Tags: refrigerator, mold, storage

My concern would be moisture buildup/mold. But if I leave it open overnight, maybe that would be enough to prevent mold?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because appliance usage questions are off topic.

Answer (score 3):

Dry it out well after it has thawed, and use a desiccant (moisture absorber) inside. I wouldn't consider it safe from mold without that.

Comment: Good point with dessicant. Unless the items to be stored in the refrigerator have problematic moisture levels, dessicant should work even with the door shut.

Comment: Thanks all! Any idea how much desiccant I need as a function of volume?

Comment: Nope. Read the package.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if the freezer has been unplugged long enough to melt and drain any accumulated frozen condensation, it would be safe to use as storage with the door/lid open.

Because it is a mostly airtight environment, it is not suitable for closed long-term storage unless significant ventilation is added by drilling holes or leaving the door/lid open.